# Best option to profile CPU use in my program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, embedded

I am profiling CPU usage on a simple program I am writing. I have different algorithms I want to try, and I also want to know what's the impact on the total system performance.

Currently, I am using ualarm() to execute some instructions at 30Hz; every 15 of those interruptions (every 0.5s) I record the CPU time with getrusage() (in useconds), so I have an estimation on the  total cpu time of cpu consumption on that point in time. But to get context, I also need to know the total time elapsed in the system in that time period, so I can have the % of which is used by my program.

```
/* Main Loop */
while(1) 
{
    alarm = 0;

    /* Waiting Loop: */
    for(i=0; !alarm; i++){
    }

    count++;

    /* Do my things */

    /* Check if it's time to store cpu log: */
    if ((count%count_max) == 0)
    {
        getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &ru);
        store_cpulog(f,
                (int64_t) ru.ru_utime.tv_sec,
                (int64_t) ru.ru_utime.tv_usec,
                (int64_t) ru.ru_stime.tv_sec,
                (int64_t) ru.ru_stime.tv_usec);
    }


}
```

I have different options, but I don't know which one will provide the most exact result:

1. Use `ualarm` for the timing. Currently it's programmed to signal every 0.5 seconds, so I can take those 0.5 seconds as the CPU time. Seems quite obvious to use, but it's the best option?
2. Use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC)`: it provides readings with a `nanosec` resolution.
3. Use `gettimeofday()`: provides readings with a `usec` resolution. I've found opinions against using it.

Any recommendation? Thanks.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but why are you using a busy loop instead of sleeping?

Comment: I need to run my algorithm at 30Hz, it is, 30 times per second or every 33ms. My algorithm is also much faster than that. If use sleep (or nanosleep), the algorithm will be ran every 33ms + execution_time(algorithm). The busy loop is to wait 33ms - execution_timie(algorithm). I hope it is clear :)

Comment: Have you looked at code profiling tools? Or do these not work/exist on the embedded system you are using?

Comment: Not available, unfortunately.

Comment: You could still sleep if you either get the time at the end of execution and sleep until the next time quanta. or use something like  `clock_nanosleep()` with an absolute time (again as prev + 33ms).

Comment: I can only assume the conveniently omitted declaration of `alarm` is volatile. Further, the `i` is entirely unneeded, as you can achieve the same result with `while (!alarm);` assuming the aforementioned alarm is so. Not that it is a good idea either way.

Comment: Yep, alarm is volatile. That part of the code is working flawlessly, it's not worrying me.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to use system function [time](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm) and don't using busy loop (like @Hasturkun say) in your program. Call in console:

```
time /path/to/my/program
```

and after execution of it you get something like:

```
real    0m1.465s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m1.210s
```

Not sure about precision, if it is enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) is possibly the best application for profiling C/C++ code under linux. Use it with pride:)

Comment: Main problem here is that it's 'propietary' embedded Linux, and I am quite limited in options, including callgrind.